# Need GUI tool for querying INGRES database

Tags: ingres

Have to work with Ingres DB right now, it  has very uncomfortable GUI interface  called Visual DBA. Is there any other interfaces which I can use to fork with this DB? need some think  like SSMS, or may  be there is some plugins which can be used in Visual DBA which can make work  with it  more user friendly.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: http://community.actian.com/w/index.php/Ingres_Database_Workbench_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Ingres? Ingres 10.0 and above have a tool called Director which is an alternative to Visual DBA. Some people also use a JDBC tool called Squirrel (see http://community.actian.com/wiki/Squirrel_Howto - use the Ingres 2006 configuration)

Comment: do you know how to connect Director to my  server? I constantly receiving unable to get the list of installations for IP `java.net.sockettimeoutexception connect` timed out

Comment: I think its cannot  reach IP address on which i have my server but  doesnt  know how to solve this problem

Comment: Your Ingres instance should have a process called a management server, "mgmtsvr". It's this that Director connects to. If it's not running in a particular instance run "mgmtsvr start". To connect it uses port 16902 - so this must be opened if your server is behind a firewall. There's a Director User Guide in the documentation. You can download the docs from esd.actian.com.